# Release is not triggered upon creation of a pull request in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

I am not able to trigger a pull request release by creation of a pull request.
Please check what I am doing wrong.

First I set a **Pull request trigger** to **Enabled** for the required artifact.
[image: Set Pull request trigger to Enabled]

Then I enable **Pull request deployment** for **Testing** stage
[image: Set pull request deployment to Enable for Testing stage]

The latest build run is successful for the source pipeline:
[image: The latest build run is successful for the source pipeline]

But when I create a pull request (either manually or programatically as a final step in the source build pipeline), a new release is not triggered.
[image: Pull request]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your screenshot, your build is triggered manually, you need to set a branch policy for the master branch to make the build triggered by pull request.

[image]

[image]

This is because you select build as the artifact source type. If you choose azure repo as  source type, you do not need to set this branch policy.

Here is a [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deploy-pull-request-builds?view=azure-devops) you can refer to .